# Integrating Spring MVC Rest service with google cloud app engine and cloud mysql

Tags: spring, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, database-connection, google-cloud-sql

I have a rest web services project in spring which i want to deploy in Google Cloud app engine and want to access the google cloud mysql database from my project,i don't know how to do that as i am new to google cloud platform.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure of the question(s): you do not know how to connect App Engine to Cloud SQL or how to deploy a Spring application in App Engine, or both?

1. Spring and App Engine Standard
   [This codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cloud-app-engine-springboot/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Findex#0) is a good starting point for creating a Spring Boot Java application on Google App Engine. You can also check [this Github repo](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/getting-started-java/tree/master/appengine-standard-java8/springboot-appengine-standard) as it's a HelloWorld, Java 8, Spring Boot for App Engine Standard. Later, check [this article](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/spring_optimization) on optimizing their interoperability.
2. App Engine Standard and Google Cloud SQL
   Check out the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/cloud-sql/) from Google Cloud Platform. It's a very good starting point. The former document is found in App Engine's documentation, targeting connections to Cloud SQL. [This one](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-app-engine) is in Cloud SQL's documentation, targeting connections from App Engine.

The task itself involves several technologies so your question cannot really be answered *specifically*. I suggest starting with those documents, run some *Hello World* tests, some Quickstarts ([example](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/tree/master/appengine/cloudsql)) and then come up with specific questions if problems are encountered.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Tudormi ..I will try with basic implementation and will ask if any problem comes.

Answer (score 0):

There is actually a project that can help you with this - [Spring Cloud GCP](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gcp).

Checkout the [Cloud SQL sample app](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gcp/tree/master/spring-cloud-gcp-samples/spring-cloud-gcp-sql-sample) and the [Spring Pet Clinic using Spring Cloud SQL starter
codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cloud-spring-petclinic-cloudsql).